# How do I remove the element with fewest sets in a list and only keep the one with the most?

Tags: python, list, set

I have a list where each element contains an unknown number of sets. (The sets in the list varies depending on choices the user do in the program.) Now I want to remove all the elements with the fewest number of sets and only keep the one or ones that contains the most number of sets.

My list can look like this:

```
[{'Chocolate'}, {'Chocolate'}, {'JellyBean', 'Chips'}]
```

In this case, I would have wanted to keep just the last element because it contains two sets and the rest only one set. But sometimes there are several elements with the highest number of sets and then I want to keep them all.

I have tried to do something like:

```
if min(len(list)) != max(len(list)):

list.remove(min(len(list)))
```

but Python just says **"'int' object is not iterable"** and I can understand why but not how to think instead.

Would be very thankful if someone helped me!

Comment: A `set` refers to an unordered collection of elements, i.e. `{'JellyBean', 'Chips'}` is one set, and `{'Chocolate'}`  is one set. What you have is a list where each element is a set. You want to remove the set with the least elements. This can be done with `list.remove(min(list, key = len))`

Comment: You mean fewest elements **in** in a set? `{a}` and `{a, b}` are both singular sets...

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to iterate the list once to determine the max and then again to find the elements you want to keep.  There will be fancier solutions to do it the most efficient way possible but will be harder to understand.

```
example_list = [('Chocolate'), ('Chocolate'), ('JellyBean', 'Chips')]
max_length = 0
for item in example_list:
    if len(item) > max_length:
        max_length = len(item)
new_list = []
for item in example_list:
    if len(item) == max_length:
        new_list.append(item)
```

You might be able to do remove but normally Python gets mad about changing something you are actively iterating through.

Comment: Thank you for sharing an easy code that I could understand! Very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a new list wherein it has the max number of elements. Try below:

```
list_of_sets= [{'Chocolate'}, {'Chocolate', 'Candy'}, {'JellyBean', 'Chips'}]
max_len=max(len(s) for s in list_of_sets)
final_list = [s for s in list_of_sets if len(s)==max_len]
final_list
```

Result:

```
  [{'Candy', 'Chocolate'}, {'Chips', 'JellyBean'}]
```

Comment: Thank you! Your code was very good looking but hard to understand if your new at programming

Comment: you will get used to the language. this script is basically the same with giraffeman91 but shorter. It is one of the things that people like about python. brevity.